# How to get Swagger API JS function names?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm new to [Wordnik](http://developer.wordnik.com/docs.html) and [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) in general. I'm interacting with it through the [Node.js JS module](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js).

When looking at the generated Swagger UI pages, such as the sample [Petstore Swagger](http://petstore.swagger.io/#/) one:

[image]

it is difficult to tell what the JavaScript functions should be when querying the server.

By JavaScript functions, I mean similar to the Petstore sample example (from the swagger-js docs):

```
var Swagger = require('swagger-client');

var client = new Swagger({
  url: 'http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json',
  success: function() {
    client.pet.getPetById({petId:7},{responseContentType: 'application/json'},function(pet){
      console.log('pet', pet);
    });
  }
});
```

After connecting to `swagger.json`, how do they know the function to query the `getPetById()` function when the docs only show `GET /pet/{petId}`?

When using the Wordnik API, I've found it a general rule of thumb to use the `get{DATATYPE}()` function (with `{DATATYPE}` replaced with an appropriate value, of course), but the pattern has broken with `getPronunciation()` — it doesn't work. I don't believe the docs say it anywhere.

How could I find the JS functions for Swagger APIs?

Comment: It's written in the swagger.json file, look for `operationId`.

Comment: @ShanShan Where is the swagger.json file located?

Comment: For the petstore example, `operationId` is used: http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json You can see it in the doc: http://swagger.io/specification/ (search for operationId).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaScript method name is the same as the `nickname` and/or `operationId` field of each operation in the Swagger document, depending on which one is available.

This is an example from the [Wordnik](http://developer.wordnik.com/docs.html):

```
"path": "/word.{format}/{word}/pronunciations",
"description": "",
"operations": [
    {
    ...
    "nickname": "getTextPronunciations",
    "responseClass": "List[TextPron]"
    }
  ]
},
```

In this example `getTextPronunciations` is the JS method name.

In Wordnik, you can get the swagger.json by clicking on the *Raw* button on the word section of the document (next to the Expand Operations button). You can find all the other swagger.json files here: http://developer.wordnik.com/v4/

Comment: I didn't see the nickname field. Thanks a ton!

Comment: FYI `nickname` is a swagger 1.2 definition construct.  For swagger 2.0, you would use `operationId`, which is optional.  If not present, it'll autogenerate it.  In general, you can always reference the apis array to see what is found in the client

Comment: Thanks @fehguy for clarification.